# Getting JSON by using Alamofire and decode - Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, decode

I have an API and I also want to get request.
But I try to using JSONDecoder to convert data type and I failed.
I don't know how to decode this Json like following data.
I want to take **json["response"]** contents setting my User struct.
Have any suggestion to me?
Thanks.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4865 "No value associated with key id ("id")." UserInfo={NSCodingPath=(
>   ), NSDebugDescription=No value associated with key id ("id").}

This is JSON Data:

```
{
"status": "success",
"response": {
"id": "1130f1e48b608f79c5f350dd",
"name": "Jack",
},
"errors": ""
}
```

```
enum RestfulAPI:String {
    case userInfo = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a796fb92e00002a009a5a49"

    func get(parameters:[String : Any]? = nil,success:@escaping (_ response : Data)->(), failure : @escaping (_ error : Error)->()){
        let url = self.rawValue
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
                case .success:
                if let data = response.data {
                    success(data)
                }
                case .failure(let error):
                    failure(error)
            }
       }
    }    
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}
```

usage:

```
RestfulAPI.userInfo.get(success: { data in
     do {
         let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
         print("==) ", user.id, user.name)
     }catch let error as NSError{
         print(error)
     }
 }) { (error) in
        print(error)
 }
```

Comment: error says what are you doing wrong, read it

Comment: Use this library to create models class of you JSON and parse. https://github.com/insanoid/SwiftyJSONAccelerator

Comment: But I using Swift 4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key `id` is not on the level where you expect it. That's what the error message states.
The keys `id` and `name` are in the (sub)dictionary for key `response`.

So you need an umbrella struct

```
struct Root : Decodable {
   let status: String
   let response: User
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}
```

Then decode

```
let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
let user = root.response
```