# Extract response data from api call in alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i've read many documents about getting the response object from the api , but cant derive how to extract the data. I've used alamofire for api call . The api call is like

```
AF.request("http://10.177.41.163:9000/signup",
                   method: .post,
                   parameters: parameters,
                   encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseJSON{ response in
                   print(response.result)
```

in my print statement i get the responses as

```
`success({
    error =     {
        code = PC05;
        message = "User already exsists";
    };
    payload =     {
    };
    success = 0;
})`
```

which is fine , but i want to extract suppose the error code, how to achieve that? and in general  how to extract data from responses in swift.

Comment: You should give a try to Postman.

Comment: Learn how to use `Codable`. Use [this app](https://app.quicktype.io) to create `Model` and parsing code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting JSON by using Alamofire and decode - Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639299/getting-json-by-using-alamofire-and-decode-swift-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the jSON response, so create a Model to decode this, of course also check the response if it was successful before, you'll set an example:

Declare yourself a model:

```
struct RootResponse : Decodable {
    var error: ErrorStruct
    var payload: PayloadStruct
    var success: Int
}

struct ErrorStruct: Decodable {
    var code: String
    var message: String
}

struct PayloadStruct : Decodable {
    var ?
}
```

Once you've declared your model based on your jSON response, then you can switch to the function that makes the request to you:

```
AF.request("http://10.177.41.163:9000/signup",
                   method: .post,
                   parameters: parameters,
                   encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseJSON{ response in
                   print(response.result) 

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let data = response.data {
                        print(data)
                        // Convert This in JSON
                        do {
                            let responseDecoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootResponse.self, from: data)
                            print("USER: ", responseDecoded.error.code, "Etc...")
                        }catch let error as NSError{
                            print(error)
                        }

                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error:", error)
                }

}
```

I hope that's been helpful.

Comment: Better use `responseData` instead of `responseJSON` so that your success case will be `.success(let data)`.

Comment: Using `responseJSON` to decode `Data` is redundant. Use `responseDecodable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
AF.request("http://10.177.41.163:9000/signup",
                   method: .post,
                   parameters: parameters,
                   encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseJSON{ response in
                   print(response.result)

                   let responseJSON = JSON(response.result) // response converted in json format

                   let statusCode = responseJSON["error"]["code"].stringValue // You can get status code
```

Note : Install pod 'SwiftyJSON' to convert response.result in JSON format.

Comment: Since Swift 4 SwiftyJSON has become obsolete in favor of `Codable`.

Comment: its a single object , like it has three key, error, payload and success. but why is it enclose inside the success() like this?

Comment: @MaheshShahane , ive tried exactly like yours but it prints nothing in the console. but it hsould print right? coz  ive tried in postman and normal app

Comment: @GauravRoy can up please update the code what you did.

Comment: try to print responseJSON .

Comment: @MaheshShahane i guess im doing someting wrong in my code. thats why such errors emerge. pretty new to swift too btw.